# append meta data for same url with different query string using jquery

Tags: javascript

I am new to Drupal. I want to append the url parameter as well as meta data for the same content page onChange or onSelect through jquery. How can I do this?. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Note- I know how to append the url for normal html page using the Jquery but not know how to do it in Drupal.

Comment: are you asking How to add custom js code in drupal

Comment: No, I want to add different metadata to the same content page on selection of select option & appending the selected option to the url and also it also helps me to understand that how to create multiple aliases for one base url.